# Should I replace the neutral wire that I accidentally cut in a Romex cable when installing a new outlet?

Tags: electrical, wire

So I'm installing a new outlet in my home. There's an existing Romex cable that goes up the wall into my attic above the new outlet. When I was stripping the wire to go in the box, I accidentally severed the neutral white wire.

I was able to get the sheathed wire into the junction box by about an inch and reattach the white wire with a twist-on cap inside the box. Is this OK or do I need to replace the entire cable?

Answer (score 2):

1. Is it easier to replace the cable now than later?
2. Do you wish you were able to make that wirenut connection better?
3. Did you install the receptacle to use for a heavy electrical load,
   dedicated or not?

   If you answered yes to one or more of the questions, replace the cable.

Comment: It sounds like that cable was drawn tight to make that connection as well. If that is the case, replace the cable. Wire expands and contracts when under load.

Comment: The intended use of the outlet should NEVER play into it.  A future owner or user may have different choices.